# Change URL of shipping cost link

Tags: magento-1.9, url

I need to change the URL of the shipping cost link:

[image]

Thought this can be done in the backend but i didn't find the option. Anyone know where to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it randomly by myself.

As I guessed it can be changed in the backend:

> System -> Catalog -> Catalog -> Price (Tab) -> CMS Page for Shipping Info